# WebGL Video on Chrome sometimes black, sometimes frozen

Tags: video, three.js, html5-video, webgl, aframe

I'm using WebM video in WebGL (Three.js) for 360 video and other things.

Every now and again I get a black video or video frozen on the first frame, but the sound can be heard in the background. It's really random when it can happen, and freshing the browser and it goes away.  This is on Chrome.

I'm switching these videos into the same video element by adding them as a new source.

```
  //first removing old one
   while(videoEl.firstChild)
     videoEl.removeChild(videoEl.firstChild)

videoEl.load()

//then adding new one
 const source = document.createElement('source')
 source.setAttribute('src',  ]asset.remoteUrl)
 videoEl.appendChild(source)
```

The video is the material for the 3D sphere or plane.

There are no errors or anything obvious I can debug when this happens. How do I find the problem?

Comment: Maybe these might help... **(1)** Try doing your `load()` only after setting a "src" URL **(2)** All your above could be possibly replaced with just one line _eg:_  `videoEl.setAttribute("src", (asset.remoteUrl) )` so avoid need for creating multiple new sources, just set a new URL to the existing video element. **(3)** I use standard webGL (not via ThreeJS) and only got such problem if there is a lot of GPU instances running at same time (even other video site's tabs can affect mine). Check your system (free memory / GPU usage etc) in case it's actually a hardware issue & not a coding issue.

Comment: Thanks that's been really helpful

Comment: I would suspect hardware first since doing a page refresh fixes it.  Refreshing is just clearing of memory and a re-init of the GPU instance. So either your `<source>` objects are not removed as immediately as you think, thus affecting memory (_eg:_ video freezes, etc). In Chrome, trying using **task manager** tool to "end task" the GPU process, then switch back to your webGL tab?